# How to redirect in a php project running in localhost?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, wamp

Suppose i have a link generated in php:

`http://localhost/Example/www.someDomain.com`

now i would like to go to www.someDomain.com , can you please help me with the proper method (probably via .htaccess) to redirect to desired location.

I tried using php header function and js window.location.replace(" ") but it dint' helped.

***Problem with `window.location.replace("www.someDomain.com")` is that instead of redirectng to www.someDomain.com , the page redirects to `http://localhost/www.someDomain.com`

---

I am using Wamp server if it helps.
Help please and also suggest some nice resource to study about .htaccess
Thanks

Comment: `http://` before the `www` with the window.location.replace.

Comment: If the url contains http:// or get parameters, I believe it would get rather sticky. If you don't mind using Javascript, you can use a hash: `http://localhost/Example#www.someDomain.com` then in Javascript you'd simply get it with `var url = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');` then `window.location.replace('http://'+url);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood.

you need to put te entire URL with "http://".

Javascript:

```
<script>
window.location.href=("URL");
</script>
```

OR in php:

```
<?php
header("location:$redirect");
?>
```

Comment: Because the browser assumed is this a file not a URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location` or PHP `header()` function, but for redirect to another site must prefix with `http://`.

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com");
```

You can also do the same through Apache `.htaccess` with a **Redirect rule**.

Answer (score 0):

htaccess is NOT going to help you at all. If all your links look like: `http://localhost/...` then in order for htaccess to redirect, everyone who goes to your site would have to be running a webserver on their local machine and have an htaccess file that redirects to your site.

You need to fix your php scripts so they generate the correct hostname. Using javascript to redirect isn't even a viable solution, because in order for the location to be "localhost", they're already loading no content because they're trying to connect to their own machine.

If for whatever crazy reason you can't fix your scripts, you may have to look into using [mod_proxy_html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) on your site and dynamically change all your "localhost" to your domain.

Comment: this is for a personal project running on my local machine. I just am curious about possibilities of how htaccess can be used for url rewrite. What i want is to extract parts of a url to produce a new url... for example a request to 'www.example.com/a/b' should be redirected to 'www.b.com'